# Angular JS ng-bind-html CSS Style Not apply inside ul , li tag Why?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to bind HTML code using `ng-bind-html` in angularJS,

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="cls_editors_output_sec" ng-repeat="content in dynamicProgramContents[group.id]">
    <li><p>{{content.title}}</p>
    <li>
        <ng-bind-html ng-bind-html="content.content"></ng-bind-html>
    </li>
</ul>
<!--<label ng-bind-html="content.content"></label>-->
```

I've also tried,

```
<div ng-repeat="content in dynamicProgramContents[group.id]">
  <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="content.content"></p>
</div>
```

I've no CSS style added,I've checked that content.content inside ng-repeat,

I got like content below,

```
<p style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; margin-left: 0in; text-align: justify; direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: embed; word-break: normal;"><br /><span style="font-size: 36pt;"><em><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Permanent visa for applicants who can prove their outstanding achievements</span> in sports, arts, performance, academia and research, and that such achievements are not going to diminish in the future. Applicants must also be nominated by an eligible person/organisation, who/which has a national reputation in Australia in the same field as the person applying for this visa.</span></em></span></p>
```

I can't understand what's wrong in my code. Please give me any kind of tips. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us how does data structure of `dynamicProgramContents` look like.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at ngSanitize

Comment: thanx for your reply,dynamicprogramContent look like longtext Its Read correct only but ng-bind-html not apply Css Style